# Typescript infer Generic types from Implementation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So I am working on a react-native project.
I was hoping if one could infer Generic types from implementation.

```
type itemType<T> = { item: T };

const someItem = {
    item: 'Some String'
};

type someItemType = typeof someItem;
// So Here someItemType will be {item: string}, i want it to be itemType<string> and 
// in this example i have implemented itemType but in real use case i want to infer 
//it from the actual implementation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial inference on variables is not supported at present in typescript. Your only option is to use the inference behavior of function:

```
type itemType<T> = { item: T };
const createItemType = <T>(o: itemType<T>) => o;

const someItem = createItemType({ //someItem is typed as itemType<string>
    item: 'Some String'
})
```

Just one note, it might not matter that in your original example  someItem is typed as `{item: string},` it will still be assignable to `itemType<string>` because typescript uses structural compatibility to determine assignability. So if the structure is compatible all is ok:

```
type itemType<T> = { item: T };

const someItem ={ 
    item: 'Some String'
}
const someOtherItem: itemType<string> = someItem // ok
```

Comment: In this case, I wouldn't write extra runtime code as there is no benefit to making the names match outside of a nominal type system.

Comment: @Fenton agreed, that is why I pointed out it does not much matter what the actual type if `someItem` is, al least with regard to future assignability to `itemType<string>`. There might be benefit in ensuring the object conforms to the `itemType<T>` interface at declaration site, rather than on future usage, I'd expect the perf impact of the identity function used to not be too high in most scenarios.

Comment: I famously don't worry about performance impact - I worry about having to go back and change the program in six months :)

Comment: @Fenton I must admit, while I do worry about that I have used such functions to help with inference all in one line `const someItem = (<T>(o: itemType<T>) => o)({ 
    item: 'Some String'
})` I will understand then in 6 months.. not sure anybody else understands them right now :)

Comment: I have some code that looks a bit like this in C#. I think if you flash it up for half a second and ask people to guess what they saw, and they answer "A Regular Expression" it's time to refactor.

Comment: Not sure if this is what i am looking for. Just a question is there no way to derive itemType<T> from someItem. I have been thinking about it but cannot figure it out.

Comment: You can get the type of a variable, `type someItemType = typeof someItem;` but you can't get a generic type from it ..

Comment: Ok, That was exactly what is was asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter whether the type is defined as `{ item: string }` or `itemType<string>` as TypeScript uses structural typing. That means the two are the same, because they have identical structures.

For example, you can assign values of either type to each other type:

```
type itemType<T> = { item: T };

const someItem = {
    item: 'Some String'
};

type someItemType = typeof someItem;

const a: itemType<string> = { item: 'exmaple a' };
const b: someItemType = { item: 'exmaple b' };

let c: itemType<string>;

c = a;
c = b;

let d: someItemType;

d = a;
d = b;
```

Comment: So the thing is i do not want to write type itemType<T> = { item: T }; i want to infer it from the implementation.

Comment: That way if i update the original object my types are automatically updated.

Comment: If you update the original object, it may no longer be an `itemType<T>`.